# Designing a better API?

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns, oop

1. What are the best practices and patterns to be followed for designing APIs?
2. How to achieve implementation hiding the best way (C++/Java)?
3. Designing APIs which are generic in nature?
4. Any reference books/links which guide with neat examples to beginners?

Comment: http://pkisensee.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!3C84486A9D832EB7!410.entry and to some extent http://gamearchitect.net/2008/09/19/good-middleware/ may be worth a read.

Comment: There are plenty of good answers so no need to add another. But in my opinion a good API is: 1) minimal 2) complete 3) consistent 4) easy to use right and hard to use wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be useful for you.

[The Little Manual of API Design (wayback machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090520234149/http://chaos.troll.no/~shausman/api-design/api-design.pdf)

[The Little Manual of API Design (original; dead)](http://chaos.troll.no/~shausman/api-design/api-design.pdf)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure I have a great answer for all of your individual questions there but I think I do have a good answer for the very first one.

Try to use it before it is ever written. By that I mean, write unit tests for the code as if it really did exist. Write some of the code that will be using the API before you've even written one line of the API. As you try to use it you'll quickly see what works and what doesn't work in the design you had in mind and *you'll be quick to change it to match its actual use because you haven't yet written any of the actual code*.

There's never any friction to changing something if you haven't committed any of it to code, but the moment you do, there is often some measure of reluctance to do so.

Comment: I've often found it's better to write an "Example app" using the API rather than just unit tests, so you can see how the API could be used in a real environment.

Answer (score 5):

Q4:

- [How to Design a Good API & Why it Matters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw) - Great video, well worth the time spent watching it.

In my opinion, Josh Bloch has the best ideas when it comes to writing good APIs, and he can explain them in a very easy-to-understand manner. The video above will address Q1-3 for you.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to check **[How to Design a Good API & Why it Matters](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design)**

> A well-written API can be a great
>   asset to the organization that wrote
>   it and to all that use it. Given the
>   importance of good API design,
>   surprisingly little has been written
>   on the subject. In this talk (recorded
>   at Javapolis), Java library designer
>   Joshua Bloch teaches how to design
>   good APIs, with many examples of what
>   good and bad APIs look like.
>
> http://www.infoq.com/presentations/effective-api-design

Also you can read the book [**Practical API Design: Confessions of a Java™ Framework Architect**](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430209737). I didn't read it so I'm not sure if it contents could be useful to you.

Another resource to check:  [**How To Design a (module) API**](http://openide.netbeans.org/tutorial/api-design.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have a tip regarding point 3 (generic API design):

Start of basing your API on **specific use-cases**; Make your design specific, not generic - Then genericise later ***if*** you discover that the API can be re-used.

In the past I've seen APIs refactored to the point where they are so generic that one of the method parameters is a "Parameters" object or worse still, a DOM tree corresponding to an artbitrary piece of XML; e.g.

```
void processData(Parameters reportParams);
```

With this uber-generic approach:

- Bugs are less likely to be discovered at compile-time or by eyeballing the code and will surface at runtime, making them difficult to track down.
- Code will be less readable and less self-documenting making it difficult to use or implement.
- The API implementation will become ugly as internally it needs to decompose this "Parameters" object into a specific use-case and act upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Apress - Practical API Design - Confessions of a Java Architect - 2008

Pragmatic - Interface Oriented Design - 2006

Answer (score 1):

Read [*Effective Java*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) by Josh Bloch.   The book is great for any Java programmer, but also addresses lots of issues surrounding the creation of a useful API.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [podcast](http://www.se-radio.net/2009/08/episode-143-api-design-with-jim-des-rivieres/)

Its talks about some really good concepts regarding api design.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following guidelines:

1) use established or known methods, examples:

```
createPatientRecord();
createPatientAppointment();
createPatientCheckup();
```

2) returning values:

- throw an exception if any
- if no object found, return null
- if several objects, return empty list not null

3) consistent arguments ordering/sequence

```
recallPatientRecord(long patientId, long hospitalId);
recallPatientRecord(long patientId);
recallPatientRecord(long patientId, long hospitalId, int disciplineCode);
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is almost impossible to answer.  It may not even be a proper question for Stack Overflow (Person A: How do I do solve specific problem?  Person B: Here is this definitive answer).

> 1.What are the best practices and patterns to be followed for designing APIs

What programming language are we talking about?  What field of problem domains are we talking about?  Because what works for one programming language / problem domain may not work well in another programming language / problem domain.

> 2.How to achieve implementation hiding the best way (C++/Java)

There is an answer to that question, and it is too long to write here.  In fact, it is so long that a website reference wouldn't be enough.  There are many websites and books, when combined together, will answer that question.  Oh, and I'm just talking about C++.  Repeat that whole process for Java.  And for C#, and for Python, and for .... (etc.)

> 4.Any reference books/links which guide with neat examples to beginners

Pick a programming language.  Then I can provide references to books and links.  As Fred Brooks wrote, there is no silver bullet.  There is no single mentality that you can take from programming language to programming language.  What makes a good API in one programming language would be a design mistake in another programming language.  Trust me, I learned this the hard why by trying to apply C++, Delphi, and Java idioms across those languages.  It lead to bad APIs and bad code.

There are also competing schools of thought in designing APIs.  And, unfortunately, the reality is that nobody is 100% right.  In fact, you become a great API designer when you know multiple schools of thought and know when to apply a particular school of thought to a particular problem.